# Unable to translate signin page in Azure AD B2C IEF

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, identity-experience-framework

Recently wanted to translate our custom SignUpSignin policy to Italian.

We can customize the UI just fine, and translate most texts. However, we are unable to modify the "E-Mail" and the "Password" translations. The email claim is translated just fine in other policies (e.g. password reset).

We tried various claim names without success (signInName, email, password, ...). Translations in german did not work either.

```
 <UserJourney Id="SignUpOrSignIn">
  <OrchestrationSteps>
    <OrchestrationStep Order="1" 
      Type="CombinedSignInAndSignUp" 
      ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.signuporsignin">

...

 <ContentDefinition Id="api.signuporsignin">
    <LoadUri>our_custom_ui</LoadUri>
    <RecoveryUri>~/common/default_page_error.html</RecoveryUri>
    <DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:unifiedssp:1.0.0</DataUri>
    <Metadata>
      <Item Key="DisplayName">Signin and Signup</Item>
    </Metadata>
    <LocalizedResourcesReferences>
      <LocalizedResourcesReference Language="de" 
        LocalizedResourcesReferenceId="de" />
      <LocalizedResourcesReference Language="en" 
        LocalizedResourcesReferenceId="en" />
      <LocalizedResourcesReference Language="it" 
        LocalizedResourcesReferenceId="it" />
    </LocalizedResourcesReferences>
  </ContentDefinition>

...

 <Localization>
  <SupportedLanguages DefaultLanguage="en">
    <SupportedLanguage>en</SupportedLanguage>
    <SupportedLanguage>de</SupportedLanguage>
    <SupportedLanguage>it</SupportedLanguage>
  </SupportedLanguages>
  <LocalizedResources Id="it">
    <LocalizedStrings>
      <LocalizedString ElementType="ClaimType" 
        ElementId="email" 
        StringId="DisplayName">Indirizzo e-mail</LocalizedString>
      <LocalizedString ElementType="ClaimType" 
        ElementId="signInName" 
        StringId="DisplayName">Indirizzo e-mail</LocalizedString>
      <LocalizedString ElementType="ClaimType" 
        ElementId="password" 
        StringId="DisplayName">Some dummy text</LocalizedString>
```

**Update:**
This is my resulting html

```
 <div class="entry">
    <div class="entry-item">
      <label for="signInName">
        Indirizzo di posta elettronica
      </label>
      <div class="error itemLevel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
        <p role="alert"></p>
      </div>
      <input id="signInName" name="Indirizzo e-mail" pattern="^...$" placeholder="Indirizzo di posta elettronica" value="" tabindex="1" type="email">
    </div>
    <div class="entry-item">
      <div class="password-label">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <a id="forgotPassword" tabindex="2" href="...">Password dimenticata?</a>
      </div>
      <div class="error itemLevel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
        <p role="alert"></p>
      </div>
      <input id="password" name="Some dummy text" placeholder="Password" tabindex="1" type="password">
    </div>
    <div class="working"></div>
    <div class="buttons">
      <button id="next" tabindex="1">Accedi</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must add the `<SupportedLanguages />` element to the`<Localization />` element:

```
<BuildingBlocks>
  <Localization>
    <SupportedLanguages DefaultLanguage="en">
      <SupportedLanguage>de</SupportedLanguage>
      <SupportedLanguage>en</SupportedLanguage>
      <SupportedLanguage>it</SupportedLanguage>
    </SupportedLanguages>
  </Localization>
</BuildingBlocks>
```

Comment: This did not help unfortunately... added some information to the original post